# Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate on Chromebook Kali installation

Tags: kali-linux, chrome-book

I recently tried to install Kali Linux on a Chromebook with crouton, but then the problems began. I have installed Xfce and KDE before and didn't particularly enjoy either of them, but install Kali Linux on my main desktop and got into it (even though it is created off of Xfce). I found out that I can download Kali on my Chromebook with crouton, and followed a very similar process to download it. I used the command 'sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r kali-rolling -n kali -t xiwi' and it downloaded and installed a bunch of stuff and then I created a Unix username and password. Then, I attempted to install Xfce itself since I couldn't open up kali by itself (as my tutorial told me), and I keep getting the same error. "Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate". I have done every possible apt-get update and upgrade and even "apt-get remove gksu", to which it told me that it cannot be deleted as it doesn't exist. Then, "apt-get install gksu", where it told me "Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source", followed by the same 'gksu has no installation candidate' problem. How can I fix this, or where do I download gksu? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) Kali Linux meta question. It boils down to if you have to ask these questions Kali Linux is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading it and building it from source from the developers repository which is https://people.debian.org/~kov/gksu/ according to the developer you need to build both `libgksu` and `gksu`